# copying SQLLDR from one Oracle install to another

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am writing a shell script to import some text files into an Oracle database. This script has to in turn invoke `sqlldr`. I discovered however that this particular Oracle install (let's call it SYS1) does not have `sqlldr` in it for some reason, and I can't update it by running an installer. I did find another system (SYS2) with seemingly the same version of Oracle installed (11.2.0) which has `sqlldr.exe` in `C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN`. So I copied that exe file, plus whatever was in on SYS2 in `C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\lib` that was missing form SYS1. I also defined `ORACLE_BASE` and `ORACLE_HOME`. Still, when I invoke the copied `sqlldr.exe` on SYS1, I get:

```
Message 2100 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=ULMessage 2100 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=UL
```

What else do I need to do to be able to run the transplanted exe on SYS1? Thx!

Comment: Does SYS1 have the instant client, perhaps, while SYS2 has the full client or server installation? Mixing and matching between the two isn't likely to go very well. Can you run `sqlldr` from the other machine, or from the DB server; or if you have server access, use an external table instead?

Answer (score 0):

First thing missing is the `%ORACLE_HOME%/RDBMS/mesg/ulus.msb` fiel. There might be more things missing after you copy this one.